# How to save stereo images

Tags: saving, stereoscopy

What is the correct way to save out stereo side by side images in blender.

I hit render on my scene and I watch as it renders first the left and then the right image. However when the rendering is finished I can only see the right eye image. When I try to save a jpeg in the side by side format the resulting image is half black.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Have you searched for the term "Stereoscopy" on this site; there are several questions answered that should help you.  Also search for "blender Stereoscopy" on youTube.com

Comment: I have yes. There seems to be very little information about how it all works. I can get  simple scenes to work but when I work on something more complex it doesn't work. It seems to be that one render overwrites the first.